# Help or advice on how to manage misleading/inappropriate answers to an asked question

Tags: discussion, answers

Have just updated [How to EFI install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/208405/102029) with what I am sure concludes the answers that have been given are misleading and inappropriate to the specific question being asked.

Had previously flagged an answer as not an answer which was reviewed and the flag was marked as helpful but the answer remains. At that time I was not near 100% sure that it was important to get the answer removed. However I am now sure that the answers given (with one exception) are not relevant to the specific question nor are in any way helpful in achieving an Ubuntu install EFI mode on the hardware that is being used. These are answers that are very low scoring even compared to the question which at least confirms the question is better than the answers.
A recent answer followed suit of existing answers and earned a downvote for their cheek.

Have flagged the answers for review under "something else" and now that they have been reviewed two have been given "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"

So considering my low rep:

- How does an answer get evaluated for being appropriate to question?
- What would be the appropriate way to request removal of these misleading answers?
- Is it the Ask Ubuntu way to leave as is until a better answer is given and then wait for community voting up the better answer for it to rise to top?

Answer (score 6):

You have more than 50 and 125 reputation. Leave a comment on the answer(s) explaining briefly why it's not relevant/wrong, downvote if you truly want to drive that message home. Flagging something only gets but a few eyes on it. Leaving a comment will let everyone reading the post know your thoughts on it. Flags aren't meant directly for technical inaccuracies, technology moves, people mis-construe the problem in the question, etc. Leaving a comment not only warns others but gives the person who answered feedback and clarification. Who knows, maybe they'll be able to edit their answer to provide better information.

One exception comes to mind: If the answer is harmful to a users experience (The "`rm -rf /`" kind of answer) then please flag it as destructive so it can be reviewed for removal.